# IBM ODM Rule Execution Server Repository not loaded

Tags: java, eclipse, repository, ibm-odm

Hello I am new to ODM and its tools. I encountered a problem with connecting rule execution server's repository with my company's repository.

[image]

I can click next and go to last step until finish but when I go to http://localhost:9080/res/protected/installer.jsf again the same page is displayed. Did I do installation improperly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to finalize the wizard in this page to finish the installation of the Rule Execution Server and then there should be a button to execute the final SQL script.

Best
Emmanuel